# Declaring variable as Excel application in Access VBA generates error: User-defined type not defined

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an Access database and have data in an Excel worksheet. I need to use data from some of the cells in the Excel worksheet to update cells in a table in the Access database.

I am struggling with getting the connection to the Excel workbook worksheet.

I am trying

```
Sub test()
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = GetObject("H:/ggg.xls")
Set ws = xlWrkBk.Worksheets(1)
```

I get the error

> User-defined type not defined

for the first line

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
```

Is there a reference I need to add?

Comment: Maybe Microsoft Excel xx.x Object Library?

Comment: Was just adding Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library'. I am now getting a problem setting the workbook (note that the workbook is open already). I am trying set wb = ("Split Values.xlsm") however this is not working (getting Type Mismatch error)

Comment: I'm not sure if your `xl` is going to be the same application instance but try `set wb = xl.workbooks("Split Values.xlsm")`. If that works, everything else should fall into place.

Comment: btw, if the wb is already open then you are better running xl-to-access from excel. Access handles the sharing and message queue requests better and Excel can operate as a single threaded vba procedure.

Comment: Alternately, from access you could open another instance as read only and use that.

Comment: Generally, I recommend either using queries or `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` calls to import data from an Excel worksheet. You're reinventing the wheel here, and using OLE automation has a lot of overhead.

Comment: At least for me, I totally agree with @ErikvonAsmuth about `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`. For me, it's a lot easier.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try adding a set by 
"Dim xl As Object"

Comment: It's barely an answer - maybe an explanation of why `Object` works where `Excel.Application` doesn't.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook sorry - I was just trying to provide a simple solution for the question.

Answer (score 1):

About your code, if you are doing this in an Access Module, you need to add a reference to Microsoft Excel Object Library (mine is 12.0 because I have Excel 2007. If you have a higher version, it can be different number)

[image]

Also, your code should be something like this:

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Set xl = New Excel.Application
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("H:/ggg.xls")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
```

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.